# Is there a way to disable Ctrl+Backspace behavior in Opera 21.0.1432.0?

Tags: opera

In the version 21.0.1432.0 of Opera, Ctrl+Backspace removes the last directory of the path component of the current URL (and I'm leaving the current page when using this shortcut). So I can't use Ctrl+Backspace for simple removal of the last word from the input field where I am typing now. Is there any way to return the previous behaviour?

Comment: "Ctrl+Backspace" is actually a great feature, unless you're in a form editing.

Comment: Indeed it is bug. Opera should be smart enough to not use that short when a textbox is focused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can re-define the ParentDirectory action that has Ctrl+Backspace for the shortcut, in the file Preferences.
Release version: `%APPDATA%\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Preferences`
Developer version: `%APPDATA%\Opera Software\Opera Developer\Preferences`
For example, add as follows:

```
"Keybindings": {
  "Basic": {
    "ParentDirectory": [ "Ctrl+Shift+Backspace" ]
  }
}
```

Close Opera and backup the file Preferences before editing it.

Comment: I have tried this method but it breaks the Preferences file and Opera auto-renames it to "Preferences.bad" and creates a new Preferences file. This is my entire keybindings part, please tell me what's wrong:

"Keybindings": {
     "Basic": {
   "ParentDirectory": [ "Ctrl+Alt+Backspace" ]
  }
      "Settings": {
         "AdvancedEnabled": false
      }
   }